# AttributeError:'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

I am trying to use **LinearSVC classifier**

**Update**: Added imports

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC

LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
LinearSVC_classifier.train(featuresets)
```

But when I am trying to classify it with probabilities

```
LinearSVC_classifier.prob_classify(feats)
```

AttributeError occurs:

```
AttributeError:'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

I checked sklearn documentation, it tells that this function exist.

How to fix that?

Comment: You are using LinearSVC as a base for SklearnClassifier and it indeed does not have `predict_proba()`. Please check the [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html).

Comment: @VivekKumar you are right. But unfortunately the documentation of [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.html) wrapper for sklearn classifiers gives LinearSVM() as example, with 'predict_proba' method defined in it.

Comment: Could you add the full code of what you've imported and how `SklearnClassifier` came about? That'll be helpful to debug what's wrong in NLTK.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to sklearn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) , the method '*predict_proba*' is not defined for '*LinearSVC*'

**Workaround**:

```
LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear',probability=True))
```

Use SVC with *linear kernel*, with *probability* argument set to *True*. 
Just as explained in [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities) .

Comment: @AleksandrBaranov
[Scores and probabilities](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities)  mentions " the cross-validation involved in Platt scaling is an **expensive operation** for large datasets."

Comment: I'm not able to apply fit on LInearSVC_classifier.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `_predict_proba_lr()` instead `predict_proba`. Something like this:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf=svm.LinearSVC()

clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)

res= clf._predict_proba_lr(X_test,Y_test)
```

res would be a 2d array of probabilities of each classes against samples.

Answer (score 5):

Given your question, there is no mentioning about some outside-wrapper like NLTK (except for the tag), so it's hard to grasp what you really need!

Vivek Kumar's comment applies. LinearSVC has no support for probabilities, while SVC does.

Now some additional remarks:

- SVM-theory is not much about probabilities and the support for this comes from extra-approaches using cross-validation and an additional classifier

  - see [Platt scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling)
- the core-solver of LinearSVC, [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/FAQ.html) has not inbuilt-support for this
- the approach of *mdilip* above is a valid workaround, but:

  - SVC is based on [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and therefore slower (and maybe not ready for large-scale)
- alternative: build your own pipeline consisting of:

  - LinearSVC
  - sklearn's [probability-calibration](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibration)

It seems someone observed this [problem](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/272) before.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if there is a mistmatch between scikit-learn module versions between trained model and the predicted model.

Comment: This worked !! My training model was using 0.23.1 scikit learn version, while prediction model was using 0.23.1, I made the both 0.22.1, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy solution featuring LinearSVC wrapped with CalibratedClassifierCV. According to my experience, reduces the quality of classification.

```
>>> from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

>>> X, y = make_classification(n_features=4, random_state=0)
>>> clf = make_pipeline(CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC()))
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
>>> clf.predict_proba(make_classification(n_features=4, random_state=1,n_samples=10,)[0])
array([[0.71360647, 0.28639353],
       [0.26277422, 0.73722578],
       [0.79450968, 0.20549032],
       [0.79352606, 0.20647394],
       [0.2486062 , 0.7513938 ],
       [0.85705016, 0.14294984],
       [0.90102124, 0.09897876],
       [0.58071282, 0.41928718],
       [0.31289046, 0.68710954],
       [0.14466406, 0.85533594]])
```